# How to sum Equipment Work Order Hrs by User

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to show every user and sum each users total hours. If the UserNm has 0 WorkOrderHours I want to show a zero next to that UserNm in the WorkOrderHours column. What I have below will show me each user but it gives me the total of the WorkOrderHours in each row not the specific UserNm row.

```
Select a.UserNm, sum(b.hrs) WorkOrderHours
from Appuser a, EquipWorkOrderHrs b
Where a.DelFlg = 0 Group by a.UserNm Order by UserNm
```

Comment: How do you identify the Hrs of a User? Do you have a column in table EquipWorkOrderHrs to identify the UsrNm?

Comment: Joining correctly will solve your problem. PS sample data and expected results make for a much better question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this

```
Select a.UserNm, sum(isnull(b.hrs, 0)) WorkOrderHours
from Appuser a
     left join
     EquipWorkOrderHrs b on a.UserNm=b.UserNm
Where a.DelFlg = 0 
Group by a.UserNm
Order by a.UserNm;
```

Comment: Had to modify it to look a the UserID

Comment: Select a.UserNm, sum(isnull(b.hrs, 0)) WorkOrderHours
from Appuser a
     left join
     EquipWorkOrderHrs b on a.UserID=b.UserID
Where a.DelFlg = 0 
Group by a.UserNm
Order by a.UserNm;